# Is it possible to use lastpass without the cloud feature?

Tags: passwords, cloud-storage, lastpass

I want to use lastpass locally, without having it upload my passwords to their site. In other words, I want it to work 100% offline.
I know that the upload and cloud stuff is safe and all. Still, I'd rather have it offline. Is it possible?

Thanks

ps: The reason I choose lastpass instead of keepass is that it imports from firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use **[LastPass Pocket](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php)** for offline access.

> The reason I choose lastpass instead
>   of keepass is that it imports from
>   firefox.

There's a remedy for that:

**[ClockWork Firefox to KeePass Converter](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#ffimport)** allows passwords from Firefox to be imported into KeePass.

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: I believe that even with LastPass Pocket, you still need to upload your passwords to Lastpass first, then download your lastpass vault as an encrypted file for offline use. It doesn't look like you can add / remove passwords from your local file, you would need to add / remove from LastPass cloud, then re-download your local file. Personally I don't have a problem with using LastPass online / cloud as they do not have access to my master password, so have no way to get at my passwords (it's a 'trust-no-one' system)